# What's the difference between “bestimmt” and “das stimmt”?

Tags: word-usage, difference

I know how to use *bestimmt* inside a longer sentence, but I’ve heard it many times also as a short reply to a statement. z.B

> A: “…” [casual statement]
>   B: “Bestimmt.”

At first, it seemed to me that it has the same meaning of *stimmt* or *das stimmt* (to agree) but I was not sure. Looking on the web I found that *bestimmt* have a slightly different usage, but I didn’t get it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Bestimmt* as a single-word reply can be used for yes/no questions and indicates that the speaker believes the answer to be yes, but isn’t certain. It can also be used to support a statement that was toned down with a particle such as *wohl*. Only in this case there is an overlap with *Stimmt*, which indicates agreement and therefore doesn’t make sense with a (non-rhetorical) question.

> **A.** Wird es morgen regnen?
>   **B.** Bestimmt.
>   **A.** Dann ist es *wohl* besser, wenn ich einen Schirm einpacke.
>   **B.** Stimmt./Bestimmt.
>   **A.** Es regnet viel zu oft hier.
>   **B.** Stimmt.
>   **A.** Hängt das mit dem Klimawandel zusammen?
>   **B.** Bestimmt.

Comment: Now is much more clear :) Vielen Dank! In my head I could translate it as a -more or less ironic- "probably", while stimmt is more "that's true/make sense" . Question: the irony is necessary, or it's just a matter of contest and intonation?

Comment: @Cindie: There is not necessarily irony involved, it can be completely serious.